# Return value from array of objects inside an array of objects the functional way

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing objects which contains an array also containing objects. When the object in the array inside the array of objects contains a value of 111 I want to return the whole object inside the first array.

The code below shows one example object in the first array.

```
[  
   {  
      "id":11,
      "bookingNumber":"1210",
      "arrivalDate":"2018-09-17T22:00:00.000Z",
      "departureDate":"2019-09-18T22:00:00.000Z",
      "customerId":2,
      "fields":[
          {  
             "value":"111",
             "display_name":"RoomNumber"
          },
          {  
             "value":"otherValue",
             "display_name":"PersonInfo"
          }
      ]
    }
 ]
```

My try which returns undefined:

```
const guest = guestGroups.forEach(function (guestGroup) {
             guestGroup.fields.filter(function (fields) {
                  if (fields.value === roomNumber)
                  return guestGroup;
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether `some` of the items in the `fields` array have the `value` you're looking for:

```js
const valueToFind = '111';
const arr=[{"id":11,"bookingNumber":"1210","arrivalDate":"2018-09-17T22:00:00.000Z","departureDate":"2019-09-18T22:00:00.000Z","customerId":2,"fields":[{"value":"111","display_name":"RoomNumber"},{"value":"otherValue","display_name":"PersonInfo"}]}]

const foundObject = arr.find(
  ({ fields }) => fields.some(
    ({ value }) => value ===  valueToFind
  )
);
console.log(foundObject);
```